ActionFailed An action failed. No dependent actions succeeded in Powerautomate
I'm relatively new to PowerAutomate, but I understand the concepts of it.
I'm trying to create tasks in a teams-planner from every row in an excel-table.
So far so good..
I want to do this for every file in a specific Sharepoint-folder, and when the file is processed, I want to move this file to a subdirectory (Processed).
But whatever I do, I keep getting the error
ActionFailed. An action failed. No dependent actions succeeded.
My flow is as simple as this
Does anyone have any ideas? It's extremely frustrating..
I tried:

making the condition a positive one
adding something in the True-condition-space
ending every outcome in a compose


There seems to be a problem with your conditions. After one of your conditions is met and runs successfully, the other should be skipped.
The problem in this article seems to be the same as yours: ActionFailed. An action failed. No dependent actions succeeded.

Thanks for your reply!
One thing led to another (as always with Microsoft..).
I saw an http 400, which means that the file was locked (so I couldn't move the file).
What I end up doing, is create a sharepoint-list which gets incremented every time a file is processed.
Every time my flow starts, I create an array with all 'paths' of files to check if a file is already processed.
Not the fanciest solution, but it works...
